# Sending an Excel file from postoffice

Tags: django, django-postoffice

I am trying to send a base64-encoded excel file through Django [post_office](https://github.com/ui/django-post_office) lib. Here's the code that I have now

An example of encoded content:

```
body = 'UEsDBBQAAAAIAAAAPwBhXUk6TwEAAI8EAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbK2Uy27CMBBF9/2KyNsqMXRRVRWBRR/LFqn0A1x7Qiwc2/IMFP6+k/BQW1Gggk2sZO7cc8eOPBgtG5ctIKENvhT9oicy8DoY66eleJ8853ciQ1LeKBc8lGIFKEbDq8FkFQEzbvZYipoo3kuJuoZGYREieK5UITWK+DVNZVR6pqYgb3q9W6mDJ/CUU+shhoNHqNTcUfa05M/rIAkciuxhLWxZpVAxOqsVcV0uvPlFyTeEgjs7DdY24jULhNxLaCt/AzZ9r7wzyRrIxirRi2pYJU3Q4xQiStYXh132xAxVZTWwx7zhlgLaQAZMHtkSElnYZT7I1iHB/+HbPWq7TyQunURaOcCzR8WYQBmsAahxxdr0CJn4f4L1s382v7M5AvwMafYRwuzSw7Zr0SjrT+B3YpTdcv7UP4Ps/I8dea0SmDdKfA1c/OS/e29zyO4+GX4BUEsDBBQAAAAIAAAAPwDyn0na6QAAAEsCAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHOtksFOwzAMQO98ReT7mm5ICKGluyCk3SY0PsAkbhu1jaPEg+7viZBADI1pB45x7Odny+vNPI3qjVL2HAwsqxoUBcvOh87Ay/5pcQ8qCwaHIwcycKQMm+Zm/UwjSqnJvY9ZFUjIBnqR+KB1tj1NmCuOFMpPy2lCKc/U6Yh2wI70qq7vdPrJgOaEqbbOQNq6Jaj9MdI1bG5bb+mR7WGiIGda/MooZEwdiYF51O+chlfmoSpQ0OddVte7/D2nnkjQoaC2nGgRU6lO4stav3Uc210J58+MS0K3/7kcmoWCI3dZCWP8MtInN9B8AFBLAwQUAAAACAAAAD8ARHVb8OgAAAC5AgAAGgAAAHhsL19yZWxzL3dvcmtib29rLnhtbC5yZWxzrZLBasMwEETv/Qqx91p2EkopkXMphVzb9AOEtLZMbElot2n99xEJTR0IoQefxIzYmQe7683P0IsDJuqCV1AVJQj0JtjOtwo+d2+PzyCItbe6Dx4VjEiwqR/W79hrzjPkukgih3hS4Jjji5RkHA6aihDR558mpEFzlqmVUZu9blEuyvJJpmkG1FeZYmsVpK2tQOzGiP/JDk3TGXwN5mtAzzcq5HdIe3KInEN1apEVXCySp6cqcirI2zCLOWE4z+IfyEmezbsMyzkZiMc+L/QCcdb36lez1jud0H5wytc2pZjavzDy6uLqI1BLAwQUAAAACAAAAD8AzgFzhmwBAAALAwAAGAAAAHhsL3dvcmtzaGVldHMvc2hlZXQxLnhtbI2SyW6DMBCG730Ky/fGLEpbISDKoqg9VKq63R0YwAp4kO2E9u1rQxIhkkNvs/7fzNjx4qepyRGUFigT6s88SkBmmAtZJvTrc3v/RIk2XOa8RgkJ/QVNF+ld3KHa6wrAECsgdUIrY9qIMZ1V0HA9wxakzRSoGm6sq0qmWwU875uamgWe98AaLiQdFCL1Hw0sCpHBBrNDA9IMIgpqbuz4uhKtpmmcC5tz+xAFRUKXfrQOKUvjnvwtoNMjmxi++4AaMgO53Z8St9gOce+SLzbkuVZ21bvth3pTJIeCH2rzjt0ziLIyVmR+oW244WmssCOqF9ctd7fyo9DOmbngykX7nO100x9TL2ZHi8xOFevrCv9Swaz2BRDcAiyDU/sN6VUwkRuAwQgV3EaFN1HhCDURXYUTuQEVjlDhBMVGJ2x5Ca9clUJqUkNhe7zZIyVquHhvG2x7a07JDo3B5uxV9teBcp6lFYjm7LiHvfzj9A9QSwMEFAAAAAgAAAA/AIMYaiVIAQAAJgIAAA8AAAB4bC93b3JrYm9vay54bWyNUctOwzAQvPMV1t5pHmojWjWpxEtUQoBEac8m3jRWHTuyHdL+PetUKXDjtDPj3dHOerk6Nop9oXXS6BySSQwMdWmE1PscPjaP1zfAnOdacGU05nBCB6viatkbe/g05sBoXrscau/bRRS5ssaGu4lpUdNLZWzDPVG7j1xrkQtXI/pGRWkcZ1HDpYazw8L+x8NUlSzx3pRdg9qfTSwq7ml7V8vWQbGspMLtORDjbfvCG1r7qIAp7vyDkB5FDlOipsc/gu3a206qQGbxDKLiEvLNMoEV75Tf0GqjO50rnaZpFjpD11Zi736GAmXHndTC9DmkU7rsaWTJDFg/4J0UviYhi+cX7QnlvvY5zLMsDubRL/fhfmNlegj3HnBC/xTqmvYnbBeSgF2LZHAYx0quSkoTytCYTmfJHFjVKXVH2qt+NnwwCENjkuIbUEsDBBQAAAAIAAAAPwBcdNNwogAAAOsAAAAUAAAAeGwvc2hhcmVkU3RyaW5ncy54bWxdzk0KwjAQhuG9pwiz11QREUniQvAEeoDYjm0gmdTM1J/bWxERunyf4YMx+2eK6o6FQyYLy0UFCqnOTaDWwvl0nG9BsXhqfMyEFl7IsHczwyxqnBJb6ET6ndZcd5g8L3KPNF6uuSQvY5ZWc1/QN9whSop6VVUbnXwgUHUeSCysQQ0UbgMefu0MB2fEeaPFGf2JL1ym0GGMeYqPXGLzRz1+695QSwMEFAAAAAgAAAA/AGmuhBj7AQAAPQUAAA0AAAB4bC9zdHlsZXMueG1svVTfi5wwEH7vXxHyfucq9GiLevQKC4W2FG4LfY0aNZAfkoyL3l/fSeKqC3cs3ENfzMzkm29mvsTkj5OS5MytE0YXNL0/UMJ1bRqhu4L+OR3vPlHigOmGSaN5QWfu6GP5IXcwS/7ccw4EGbQraA8wfEkSV/dcMXdvBq5xpzVWMUDXdokbLGeN80lKJtnh8JAoJjQt89ZocKQ2o4aCZkugzN0LOTOJbaU0KfPaSGMJID32ESKaKR4R35gUlRU+2DIl5BzDmQ+EjhacEtpYH0xihfitkv9RKywOk4SU18NioMwHBsCtPqJDFvs0D1heo/CRJuBuoDvL5jT7uEsIC9atjG3woPeVY6jMJW8BE6zoer+CGRK/CWAUGo1gndFMespLxj6ThMtQUOjDYUbt2AhmkS7xoIX9JjagQgs3oYi5dHkTG2Gvz7IYKFHNpXz2TH/bVacU+aaW6FEdFXxvCoq/iD/Ji4niLmakiY7n37NF7h1t9i5aMrUr/1vZ6RvZ6ZZN2DDI+WjifNF7CsDN/ypFpxW/SMAuLumNFS+Y6u94jQFuqX9BQNQ+gocShp/aRYF1+CDFlaxrlPi/q6C//GMhd21Wo5Ag9CuSImczbWqGXWAVvklXVZCj4S0bJZzWzYJu9k/eiFF9XlG/xdnAgtrsH/5Opg+hg+3hK/8BUEsDBBQAAAAIAAAAPwAY+kZUsAUAAFIbAAATAAAAeGwvdGhlbWUvdGhlbWUxLnhtbO1ZTY/bRBi+8ytGvreOEzvNrpqtNtmkhe22q920qMeJPbGnGXusmcluc0PtEQkJURAXJG4cEFCplbiUX7NQBEXqX+D1R5LxZrLNtosAtTkknvHzfn/4HefqtQcxQ0dESMqTtuVcrlmIJD4PaBK2rTuD/qWWhaTCSYAZT0jbmhJpXdv64CreVBGJCQLyRG7ithUplW7atvRhG8vLPCUJ3BtxEWMFSxHagcDHwDZmdr1Wa9oxpomFEhwD19ujEfUJGmQsra0Z8x6Dr0TJbMNn4tDPJeoUOTYYO9mPnMouE+gIs7YFcgJ+PCAPlIUYlgputK1a/rHsrav2nIipFbQaXT//lHQlQTCu53QiHM4Jnb67cWVnzr9e8F/G9Xq9bs+Z88sB2PfBUmcJ6/ZbTmfGUwMVl8u8uzWv5lbxGv/GEn6j0+l4GxV8Y4F3l/CtWtPdrlfw7gLvLevf2e52mxW8t8A3l/D9KxtNt4rPQRGjyXgJncVzHpk5ZMTZDSO8BfDWLAEWKFvLroI+UatyLcb3uegDIA8uVjRBapqSEfYB18XxUFCcCcCbBGt3ii1fLm1lspD0BU1V2/ooxVARC8ir5z+8ev4UvXr+5OThs5OHP588enTy8CcD4Q2chDrhy+8+/+ubT9CfT799+fhLM17q+N9+/PTXX74wA5UOfPHVk9+fPXnx9Wd/fP/YAN8WeKjDBzQmEt0ix+iAx2CbQQAZivNRDCJMKxQ4AqQB2FNRBXhripkJ1yFV590V0ABMwOuT+xVdDyMxUdQA3I3iCnCPc9bhwmjObiZLN2eShGbhYqLjDjA+Msnungptb5JCJlMTy25EKmruM4g2DklCFMru8TEhBrJ7lFb8ukd9wSUfKXSPog6mRpcM6FCZiW7QGOIyNSkIoa74Zu8u6nBmYr9DjqpIKAjMTCwJq7jxOp4oHBs1xjHTkTexikxKHk6FX3G4VBDpkDCOegGR0kRzW0wr6u5i6ETGsO+xaVxFCkXHJuRNzLmO3OHjboTj1KgzTSId+6EcQ4pitM+VUQlerZBsDXHAycpw36VEna+s79AwMidIdmciyq5d6b8xTc5qxoxCN37fjGfwbXg0mUridAtehfsfNt4dPEn2CeT6+777vu++i313VS2v220XDdbW5+KcX7xySB5Rxg7VlJGbMm/NEpQO+rCZL3Ki+UyeRnBZiqvgQoHzayS4+piq6DDCKYhxcgmhLFmHEqVcwknAWsk7P05SMD7f82ZnQEBjtceDYruhnw3nbPJVKHVBjYzBusIaV95OmFMA15TmeGZp3pnSbM2bUA0IZwd/p1kvREPGYEaCzO8Fg1lYLjxEMsIBKWPkGA1xGmu6rfV6r2nSNhpvJ22dIOni3BXivAuIUm0pSvZyObKkukLHoJVX9yzk47RtjWCSgss4BX4ya0CYhUnb8lVpymuL+bTB5rR0aisNrohIhVQ7WEYFVX5r9uokWehf99zMDxdjgKEbradFo+X8i1rYp0NLRiPiqxU7i2V5j08UEYdRcIyGbCIOMOjtFtkVUAnPjPpsIaBC3TLxqpVfVsHpVzRldWCWRrjsSS0t9gU8v57rkK809ewVur+hKY0LNMV7d03JMhfG1kaQH6hgDBAYZTnatrhQEYculEbU7wsYHHJZoBeCsshUQix735zpSo4WfavgUTS5MFIHNESCQqdTkSBkX5V2voaZU9efrzNGZZ+ZqyvT4ndIjggbZNXbzOy3UDTrJqUjctzpoNmm6hqG/f/w5OOumHzOHg8WgtzzzCKu1vS1R8HG26lwzkdt3Wxx3Vv7UZvC4QNlX9C4qfDZYr4d8AOIPppPlAgS8VKrLL/55hB0bmnGZaz+2TFqEYLWinhf5PCpObuxwtlni3tzZ3sGX3tnu9peLlFbO8jkq6U/nvjwPsjegYPShClZvE16AEfN7uwvA+BjL0i3/gZQSwMEFAAAAAgAAAA/ANOT8nMkAQAAUAIAABEAAABkb2NQcm9wcy9jb3JlLnhtbJ2SzWrDMBCE730Ko7stKYZihO1AW3JqoNCUlt6EtElErR8ktU7evoqTOAn4lONqZr+dXVTPd7rL/sAHZU2DaEFQBkZYqcymQR+rRV6hLERuJO+sgQbtIaB5+1ALx4T18OatAx8VhCyBTGDCNWgbo2MYB7EFzUORHCaJa+s1j6n0G+y4+OEbwDNCHrGGyCWPHB+AuRuJ6ISUYkS6X98NACkwdKDBxIBpQfHFG8HrMNkwKFdOreLewaT1LI7uXVCjse/7oi8Ha8pP8dfy9X1YNVfmcCoBqK2lYMIDj9a3Nb4u0uE6HuIynXitQD7tkz7xdlrk2AcySwHYMe5Z+SyfX1YL1M7IjOakymm5opQRwmj1fRh5038B6tOQu4lnwDH37Sdo/wFQSwMEFAAAAAgAAAA/AF66p9N3AQAAEAMAABAAAABkb2NQcm9wcy9hcHAueG1snZLBTuswEEX3fEXkPXVSIfRUOUaogFjwRKUWWBtn0lg4tuUZopavx0nVkAIrsrozc3V9Mra42rU26yCi8a5kxSxnGTjtK+O2JXva3J3/YxmScpWy3kHJ9oDsSp6JVfQBIhnALCU4LFlDFBaco26gVThLY5cmtY+tolTGLfd1bTTceP3egiM+z/NLDjsCV0F1HsZAdkhcdPTX0Mrrng+fN/uQ8qS4DsEarSj9pPxvdPToa8pudxqs4NOhSEFr0O/R0F7mgk9LsdbKwjIFy1pZBMG/GuIeVL+zlTIRpeho0YEmHzM0H2lrc5a9KoQep2SdikY5YgfboRi0DUhRvvj4hg0AoeBjc5BT71SbC1kMhiROjXwESfoUcWPIAj7WKxXpF+JiSjwwsAnjuucrfvAdT/qWvfRtUC4tkI/qwbg3fAobf6MIjus8bYp1oyJU6QbGdY8NcZ+4ou39y0a5LVRHz89Bf/nPhwcui/ksT99w58ee4F9vWX4CUEsBAhQDFAAAAAgAAAA/AGFdSTpPAQAAjwQAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAICBAAAAAFtDb250ZW50X1R5cGVzXS54bWxQSwECFAMUAAAACAAAAD8A8p9J2ukAAABLAgAACwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgIGAAQAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHNQSwECFAMUAAAACAAAAD8ARHVb8OgAAAC5AgAAGgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgIGSAgAAeGwvX3JlbHMvd29ya2Jvb2sueG1sLnJlbHNQSwECFAMUAAAACAAAAD8AzgFzhmwBAAALAwAAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgIGyAwAAeGwvd29ya3NoZWV0cy9zaGVldDEueG1sUEsBAhQDFAAAAAgAAAA/AIMYaiVIAQAAJgIAAA8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAICBVAUAAHhsL3dvcmtib29rLnhtbFBLAQIUAxQAAAAIAAAAPwBcdNNwogAAAOsAAAAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAgckGAAB4bC9zaGFyZWRTdHJpbmdzLnhtbFBLAQIUAxQAAAAIAAAAPwBproQY+wEAAD0FAAANAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAgZ0HAAB4bC9zdHlsZXMueG1sUEsBAhQDFAAAAAgAAAA/ABj6RlSwBQAAUhsAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAICBwwkAAHhsL3RoZW1lL3RoZW1lMS54bWxQSwECFAMUAAAACAAAAD8A05PycyQBAABQAgAAEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgIGkDwAAZG9jUHJvcHMvY29yZS54bWxQSwECFAMUAAAACAAAAD8AXrqn03cBAAAQAwAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgIH3EAAAZG9jUHJvcHMvYXBwLnhtbFBLBQYAAAAACgAKAIACAACcEgAAAAA='
```

The body above is the result of the following code:

```
import base64

f = open(file_path, 'rb')
file_content = f.read()
return base64.b64encode(file_content).decode('UTF-8')
```

The the code itself:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from post_office import mail

attachments = [{
  'name': 'example.xlsx', 
  'body': ContentFile(body), 
  'mimetype': 'application/vnd.ms-excel'}]
mail.send(to, from, attachments=attachments, **params)
```

The problem is that the content in the actual file that is sent by email looks like this:
[image]

What could be the reason for that ?

Answer (score 0):

`ContentFile` has no clue that the content you're passing it is base 64 encoded. You need to base-64-decode it first to pass the actual raw bytes of the Excel file to it.

Comment: it turns out that I have a huge gap in knowledge when it comes to data encoding.Can you please provide a code snippet of what you mean ?

Comment: `from base64 import b64decode` `ContentFile(b64decode(body))` — Though it might be worth questioning why the data is base64 encoded in the first place…

Comment: Uhm… *don't* base 64 encode it to begin with then…?!

Comment: Then what should be done ? ( Sorry for stupidity. My goal is to send an excel file content as a json message through rabbitmq...

Comment: Well, the immediate fix would be to omit `base64.b64encode(...).decode('UTF-8')` and just `return file_content`. There may be some bigger-picture improvement to the entire thing you could do, but that's hard to tell.